# Most secured way to persist data in ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, security, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm using ASP MVC application + WCF service with custom session behavior implementation. Clients receive, store and use (for authorization) session tokens. Now I'm searching for most secured way to store session token at client side in ASP MVC.

I see few ways:

1. Hidden field. Drawback: user can open page source code and get token.
2. Route value. Drawback: token is actually open. User can get it from address bar.
3. Session. I've read a lot articles with one conclusion: using Session in MVC application is a bad practice. But Session have a lot advantages as well: can be widely
   configured, can store token at server side, etc.

I'm sure there are some best practices for solving my problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You might find post by Jeff Atwood interesting http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/11/breaking-the-webs-cookie-jar.html

Comment: " using Session in MVC application is a bad practice" - Citation needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Require HTTPS connections, encrypt secure data, place in cookie.

You could also pass the token around your site, encrypted of course via a hidden field or something but your scenario is actually what cookies are made to do.

My bank sets a cookie, they should be good enough for what you are doing.

Comment: Of course I'm using https and encryption. But why you suggest to use cookies? Which benefits do they have? They're client side (session you may store at server side at least).

Comment: @zenonych.  Even if you store a session at the server side you are still setting a cookie in the users browser.  Unless you plan to pass around query strings or hidden inputs on EVERY get and post request you can't avoid cookies.